# Will Blender download onto my Chromebook?

Tags: workflow

Just wondering if I can download Blender to my Chromebook?

Comment: What happens when you try? I'm guessing you can download, but you won't be able to run it

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=chromebook

Comment: Those are not "real" computers. Much less have a "real graphic card" you´re entering the high demanding hardware world of 3D creation. Please reconsider an alienware 2019 station as main source.