# Downloading blender on chromebook google chrome

Tags: installation, compatibility

Due to me wanting to download blender and it being a complete struggle , i need help. It is driving me nuts and I just want to use blender.

Comment: it looks like you have some articles on this subject: https://chromeunboxed.com/three-ways-to-install-blender-3d-software-on-your-chromebook/   https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/ao5n6l/apparently_blender_works_on_chromebook_now_its/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132595/will-blender-download-onto-my-chromebook